# rails validate a belongs_to relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given a simple relationship where Person has_many Telephones. And a telephone only contains a telephonenumber which must be unique!

```
    class Telephone < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates_presence_of :contact_id
      belongs_to :contact

      validates :telephone, {:presence => true, :uniqueness => true}
    end


  class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :telephones
    validates_associated :telephones
    has_many :emails 
    has_many :addresses

    validates_presence_of :firstname 

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :telephones, :allow_destroy=>true

    validates_presence_of :lastname
  end


    test "telephone number must be unique" do
      john = contacts :johndoe #johndoe is a person with 1 existing number
      2.times do
        john.telephones.build :telephone=> "123" # 123 doesnt exist yet
      end
      puts Telephone.count # this gives 1
      john.save
      puts Telephone.count # this gives 3 !!!! ???
      assert not(john.valid?) # This validates unless I remove the save above
    end
```

Can someone explain the outcome of this test.

1. just calling valid? fails, but that is mentioned in the rdoc (must save first)
2. saving first does make valid? pass

**BUT** now I actually have 3 records in the database which breaks my unique requirement.

Is there a better way to do this? I don't understand the outcome of this test, it really goes against my expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok if you read the ruby documentation you will notice that they mention that validating a model is not sufficient for uniqueness. YOU MUST use database unique constraints whenever possible. Otherwise it is possible when using two processes/threads/whatever that both will do a validation check, pass as unique, and then insert same values.

tl;dr: Add a unique constraint to the db column.

Comment: I'll accept this is as the answer, I guess it's just good practice to have your DB do the heavy lifting here.

But to be fair, the docs mention the 2 process problem, NOT 1 transaction cascading down and saving its children.